# Why did PortStemmer in NLTK converts my "string" into u"string"

Tags: python, nltk, sax, stemming

```
import nltk
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


from collections import Counter

def get_tokens():
    with open('comet_interest.xml','r') as bookmark:
        text=bookmark.read()
        lowers=text.lower()

        no_punctuation=lowers.translate(None,string.punctuation)
        tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(no_punctuation)
        return tokens
#remove stopwords
tokens=get_tokens()
filtered = [w for w in tokens if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
count = Counter(filtered)
print count.most_common(10)

#stemming
from nltk.stem.porter import *

def stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer):
    stemmed = []
    for item in tokens:
        stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(item))
    return stemmed

stemmer = PorterStemmer()
stemmed = stem_tokens(filtered, stemmer)
count = Counter(stemmed)
print count.most_common(10)
```

The results show like these:

[('analysis', 13), ('spatial', 11), ('feb', 8), ('cdata', 8), ('description', 7), ('item', 6), ('many', 6), ('pm', 6), ('link', 6), ('research', 5)]

[(u'analysi', 13), (u'spatial', 11), (u'use', 11), (u'feb', 8), (u'cdata', 8), (u'scienc', 7), (u'descript', 7), (u'item', 6), (u'includ', 6), (u'mani', 6)]

**what's the problem with second one of stemming, why every words has an "u" head?**

Comment: ... because they're Unicode strings?

Comment: oh. But why the first one does't Unicode? and How to convert to string from unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kindall noted, it's becaus eof the unicode string.

But more specifically, it's because NLTK uses `from __future__ import unicode_literals` which converts **ALL** strings to unicode by default, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/stem/porter.py#L87

So let's try an experiment in python 2.x :

```
$ python
>>> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
>>> porter = PorterStemmer()
>>> word = "analysis"
>>> word
'analysis'
>>> porter.stem(word)
u'analysi'
```

We see that suddenly the stemmed word became a unicode.

Then, let's try to import the `unicode_literals`:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
>>> porter = PorterStemmer()
>>> word = "analysis"
>>> word
'analysis'
>>> porter.stem(word)
u'analysi'
>>> from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
>>> word
'analysis'
>>> word2 = "analysis"
>>> word2
u'analysis'
```

Note that all strings remains still as strings but any string variable that's new after importing unicode_literals will become unicode by default.

Comment: What does this mean for the rest of your app, or wherever you use the results of the stemming?